# How to use ssh X11 forwarding instead of VNC?

Tags: ssh, xorg, vnc

Let's say instead of installing a vnc I want to use X11 forwarding with ssh. The problem is X11 forwarding doesn't show the current desktop; it only shows you new graphical windows.

How can I use X11 forwarding to view the current desktop?

Comment: @SteveRobillard I am using Linux. I know that `gnome-session` can bring up a desktop, but that does not show the current desktop.

Comment: http://xmodulo.com/remote-control-raspberry-pi.html

Answer (score 1):

No, X11 forwarding does not show the desktop. It forwards just the applications windows to your local display. You can't forward whole desktop environment easily by standard `ssh -X pi`.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately X forwarding is not designed to be like VNC. But: 
There may be a solution with FreeNX from NoMachine. 
Unfortunately I am just starting to find out how. 
OpenNX may give what you need.